# how to remove background color in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

need to remove background color of My following bootstrap

```
#fh5co-hero .fh5co-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 9;
  background: #3b3d40; // need remove background color
  opacity: .5;
}
```

how can I do it?

Comment: Please Explain bit more .

Comment: lol. comment that line  or remove that line

Comment: did you try to remove this row of code?

Comment: comment not succuse...

Comment: remove also not sucess

Comment: I need keep background color:none;

Comment: add complete html code with css

Comment: this is bootstrap style.css line 7593

Comment: your html code?

Comment: <header id="fh5co-hero" data-section="home" role="banner" style="background: url(images/ship.jpg) top left; background-size: cover;" >

Comment: remove id `id="fh5co-hero"`

Comment: when I remove id="fh5co-hero" banner will small

Comment: use custom css (example: add css in style tag width and height)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
#fh5co-hero .fh5co-overlay {
    background-color: transparent !important;
}
```

Comment: same result here

Comment: Add this line to your stylesheet file and add your stylesheet file after the bootstrap.css on your page.

Comment: this worked in bootstrap 4 trying remove the background overlay that card-footer has.  Thanks. (2019)

Answer (score 15):

For the record, in Bootstrap 4 this can be achieved with the `bg-transparent` class.

Comment: Make sure nothing overrides or enforces a specific style. Use Dev Tools to debug.

Answer (score 4):

Please try this:

```
background-color: transparent;
```